# How to set "timeouts for RDS" via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to configure idle timeouts for RDS via PowerShell.  I have manually set them via gpedit, (Computer Configuration – Administrative Templates – Windows Components – Remote
Desktop Services – Remote Desktop Session Host – Session Time Limits), then went to the registry to find those values, they're not anywhere that I have searched.
I need to set:

1. “Set Time Limit for disconnected sessions”, “Enabled”, “30 minutes”
2. “Set Time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services Sessions”, “Enabled”, “1 Hour”
3. “Set Time limit for active Remote Desktop Services Sessions”, "Enabled", “8 hours”
4. “Set End sessions when time limits are reached”, “Enabled”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policies you have set put their settings in this registry location:
`SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services`

A full reference of the keys can be found [here](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.TerminalServer::TS_SESSIONS_Disconnected_Timeout_2).

Comment: Thank you... I saw that there but the numbers didn't add up.  After manually disabling, checking the registry and reenabling and again checking, i see that they were removed then readded.  GREATLY APPRECIATED!